# Changing the file permission using Windows API

Tags: windows, api, winapi

I am passing security descriptors to 'CreateFile' function but if the file already exists, it will be ignored. Is there any flags in CreateFile API where I can force writing security attribute? Should  I explicitly set separately? How?

Comment: You will have to set it explicitly via [SetNamedSecurityInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [SetKernelObjectSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379578%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can try `CreateFile2` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and pass in a `CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS` structure ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), specifically have a look at `dwSecurityQosFlags` and `lpSecurityAttributes`.

Comment: Should be pointed out that CreateFile2() is new for Windows 8 preview; probably not very useful at this point in time.